# View Json Result in Web browser

Tags: json

I tried to view the Json result from HTTP Response in browser through C-sharp code but crushing  my head didn't get it.So, whether we can have an option to view all **HTTP Response** results in the browser?

Comment: can you post your C-Sharp code here ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want see JSON result on your browser, 
Use : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc?hl=en (JSONView for chrome)
OR
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/jsonview/ (JSONView for Firefox)

and simply use url parameters to see JSON response in your application : http://localhost/westwindwebtoolkitweb/RestService.ashx?Method=ReturnObject&format=json&Name1=Rick&Name2=John&date=12/30/2010